# If a matrix A is non-negative definite, does that imply that A is also positive definite?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, positive-definite, positive-semidefinite

Question as in the title. I'm thinking that since the positive definite matrices are a subset of the non-negative definite matrices, then one would imply the other, i.e.  if $x\in A$ and $A\subset B$ therefore $x \in B$ I'm not sure though?

Comment: No, $0$ is non negative definite but not positive definite.

Comment: No. If $A$ is positive definite then it's also positive semidefinite (or non-negative definite), but the converse is not true

Comment: Think in terms of scalars first.

Comment: Left-handed men are a subset of all men. Are all men left-handed?